# Components are not draggable in Angular2 for Dart when bind objects using ngFor

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart, angular2-template

I've created a component which is a draggable element.

```
@Component(
    selector: 'draggable-component',
    styles: const ['.element-to-drag {background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;}'],
    template: '''
      <div class="element-to-drag"
           draggable="true"
           (dragstart)="onDragStart(\$event)"
           (dragend)="onDragEnd(\$event)">
      </div>''')
class DraggableComponent {
  void onDragStart(MouseEvent e) {
    print('onDragStart');
  }

  void onDragEnd(MouseEvent e) {
    print('onDragEnd');
  }
}
```

- When I use it as a single element it fires drag start event and **COULD BE** dragged to the drop zone.
- When I create it using ngFor of primitives list (numbers) all elements fire drag start event and **COULD BE** dragged to the drop zone.
- But when I create it using ngFor of objects list all elements fire drag start event but **COULD NOT BE** dragged to the drop zone (they are not dragged).

Here is an example:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: const [DraggableComponent, NgFor],
    styles: const ['.container {border: 1px solid red;; height: 100px; width: 100px;}'],
    template: '''
  <div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <h3>Single</h3>
    <draggable-component></draggable-component>
    <h3>Primitives</h3>
    <draggable-component *ngFor="#example of examplesPrimitives"></draggable-component>
    <h3>Objects</h3>
    <draggable-component *ngFor="#example of examples"></draggable-component>
  </div>
  ''')
class AppComponent {
  get examples => [
    {"name": 1},
    {"name": 2},
    {"name": 3},
    {"name": 4} ];

  get examplesPrimitives => [ 1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

How can I make bindings of objects draggable?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this would work so I won't leave it as an answer but you could have the `*ngFor` loop outside `<draggable-component>`  and create multiple draggable components each with their own object doing something like this `<div *ngFor="#example of examples"><draggable-component [example] = example></draggable-component.</div>` Then use an `input: [example]` inside your `draggable-component` directive.

Comment: Have you investigated the generated DOM? Are there differences? There shouldn't be differences IMHO.

Comment: Morgan G, i tried this case as well and it does not work too.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, i've checked DOM and there is no difference. I also expected no difference in the behavior but something is wrong. Gonna to check the same case in Angular2 with TypeScript.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, see comments above

Comment: @MorganG, see comments above

Comment: Just a wild guess. You could try to use a different variable than `#example` in the 2nd `*ngFor`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, originally I came with this problem from the project where object list and other variable names were used. I isolated the code to find the real problem and found the difference with primitives list and single component,

Comment: I guessed so but it was worth a try. You also don't get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks. Will try it with TypeScript a bit later, probably there is a bug in Dart implementation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, no errors in the console. Only print about drag start from my onDragStart method.

Comment: And your other related code doesn't do anything with the `examples` list like checking if mouse-over is a valid drop target or similar?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the code in this question is complete. Only bootstrap and <my-app></my-app> in the index.html are not included. Nothing more.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, proved a bug in Dart version of Angular2.

Comment: @ne4istb sorry I couldn't be more helpful!  Hopefully your github issue will be addressed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Angular2 wit Dart bug. Angular2 with TypeScript works fine in the same case.

An issue was created in Angular repository: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6975